# Intelligence of nervous system vs other human intelligence?

Tags: proteins, brain, prion

Viral proteins are shown to be used in intelligence such as for memory: https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/01/180111141450.htm

I wondered since proteins able to form prions are the most logical thing directly controlled by the soul, how intelligent is the nervous system compared with other systems the body uses for intelligence like viral proteins? Has anyone calculated the difference in computing power of them?

Comment: What are you implying by the phrase "intelligence like viral proteins"? Could you please elaborate your thoughts on it?

Comment: @ANandiΨ Viral proteins are shown to be used in intelligence such as for memory https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/01/180111141450.htm#:~:text=The%20protein%2C%20called%20Arc%2C%20is,like%20a%20protein%20from%20viruses.&text=A%20protein%20involved%20in%20cognition,like%20a%20protein%20from%20viruses.

Comment: @ANandiΨ I wonder how the non-nervous intelligence compares to nervous intelligence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Arc" is the [Activity-regulated cytoskeleton-associated protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity-regulated_cytoskeleton-associated_protein). It's one of the ["immediate early genes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_early_gene), which are genes whose expression changes very quickly in response to certain neuronal activity. They are thought to be important in mediating the changes in expression of other proteins that accompany learning and memory in neurons.

**This is not talking about any other "intelligence" or memory besides what happens in the nervous system**. It's about the *mechanisms* by which the nervous system operates. The paper (Pastuzyn et al 2018) suggests that this protein originally came to the animal genome from a virus rather than evolving from other animal genes, and that it behaves in a virus-like fashion to transfer genetic material from one cell to a neighboring cell. That's definitely interesting from an evolutionary and molecular biology perspective, but it does not mean the body "uses viral proteins for intelligence".

In an animal, these aren't "viral proteins" any more, they are animal proteins, built from DNA in animal cells and evolved alongside those animal cells. The paper is about Arc in fruit flies, though Arc is also found in vertebrates but seemingly from a different lineage; therefore the authors suggest that this has happened at least twice. It's certainly fascinating that such a rare event would happen more than once; I'm not sure if there is additional literature on this because it seems hard to believe, but I suppose it's one more element to how all the genetic variation in modern species evolved.

---

Pastuzyn, E. D., Day, C. E., Kearns, R. B., Kyrke-Smith, M., Taibi, A. V., McCormick, J., ... & Shepherd, J. D. (2018). The neuronal gene arc encodes a repurposed retrotransposon gag protein that mediates intercellular RNA transfer. Cell, 172(1-2), 275-288.